# Fastest way to measure global time (wall-clock) in multithreaded application with C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, time, c++-chrono

I am working on a high-performance library where I need to stop the time point of a thread when it finished a computation and then save that time point in a global variable, so that this global variable always holds the most recent finishing time of a thread.

Right now, I am using the C++ std:chrono library with timestamps to stop the time like:

```
auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now().time_since_epoch();
// thread calculates something
auto finish = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now().time_since_epoch();
unsigned time = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(finish-start).count();
// now I can use the needed time and also update a global variable with the finish time point.
```

**This works pretty well. But...**

A call to chrono is slower than a call to the rdtsc().

**The rdtsc version:**

```
static __inline__ ticks getticks(void)
{
     unsigned a, d;
     asm("cpuid");
     asm volatile("rdtsc" : "=a" (a), "=d" (d));

     return (((ticks)a) | (((ticks)d) << 32));
}

tick = getticks();
sleep(1); // or whatever calculation
tick1 = getticks();
time = (unsigned)((tick1-tick)/2400000/*The CPU speed*/);
```

**Comparison:**
I measured both, chrono and rdtsc, calls with the rdtsc itself to see how many ticks they need and the results are:

- chrono needed about 34096 ticks
- rdtsc needed about 1744 ticks

**Problem:**

I can't use rdtsc because it is, as far as I know, relative only. I can't use it to measure time-points, right? I don't want just durations of some calculation but also the actual finishing time point so that every thread know when the most recent finishing time happened.

**Question**: What is the fastest way to measure global time points and share across all threads?

Comment: This kind of sounds like an XY problem.  Why do you need a global time point?  Normally you should not be using timing information to synchronize multi threaded code.

Comment: Neither `rdtsc` nor `high_resolution_clock` measures "wall clock" time. They're just cycle counters. So are you looking for wall clock time or cycle counters?

Comment: You can store the tick count at program/thread start in a global variable and use that as reference for your time points. (If `rdtsc` is thread-local then that variable would have to be thread-local).

Comment: @NathanOliver I need global times so that every thread knows "since how many time units [e.g. microseconds] the last thread finished some calculation?".

Comment: NicolBolas yes but I am using the "timesinceepoch" in chrono to have global times. This is why it works but I am just wondering if there is a faster way :) Maybe my method is not the optimal solution.

@MAxLanghof thanks for the info but is this then still correct? I don't really know how rdtsc works in depth but does it count all the cycles of all running threads? Because then, for example, if 10 threads are running simultaneously, the time passed would be about 10-times more than it really is.

Comment: I edited my question to be more clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I can't use rdtsc because it is as far as I know relative only.

It is relative to some unspecified time point, e.g. CPU power on time.

> I can't use it to measure time-points, right?

You use `rdtsc` to measure *durations* in CPU cycles. You can also use the value as a time point since unspecified time. You can also find out the wall clock time of that unspecified time.

---

If you use `gcc`, [`__builtin_ia32_rdtsc` generates better assembly than hand-coded versions](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=48877).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Ok so how can I find out the wall clock time of that unsepcified time? For example to know since how many microseconds the last thread finished a computation?

Comment: You call `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now()` between 2 calls to `rdtsc`. Take the average of two `rdtsc` values - this `rdtsc` value corresponds to the wall clock returned by `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now()`.

Comment: What exactly is that tick number? I just tested rdtsc for measuring the duration of a serial loop with 1 million iterations and measured a parallelized loop with 3 threads and 3 million iterations. The result was about the same (+ some threading overhead on the parallelized loop). So this function does not count the number of cycles of all threads in total but something global?

Comment: @XHotSniperX It is the number of CPU cycles and it is a global counter. To convert it to nanoseconds divide it by the nominal CPU frequency. E.g. for 4.2GHz base frequency 7700k divide it by 4.2. _The processor monotonically increments the time-stamp counter MSR every clock cycle and resets it to 0 whenever the processor is reset. See “Time Stamp Counter” in Chapter 17 of the Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer’s Manual, Volume 3B, for specific details of the time stamp counter behavior._